# Write a program that says how many times it was ran

Tags: popularity-contest

Write a program that after running will show how many times it was ran before. You are only allowed to modify the executable itself (the code itself, or compiled version of your code), you cannot modify anything else or create new files.

Example:

```
$ ./yourprogram
0
$ ./yourprogram
1
$ ./yourprogram
2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat less trivial example than y'old bash, in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    const char *data="Da best marker in da world 0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
    FILE *f;
    int i;
    char c;
    long int pos;
    printf("%s\n",data+27);
    f=fopen(argv[0],"r+b");
    i=0;
    c=fgetc(f);
    while(!feof(f)){
        if(data[i]==c){
            i++;
            if(i==27)break;
        } else i=0;
        c=fgetc(f);
    }
    if(i!=27)return 1;
    i=0;
    pos=ftell(f);
    c=fgetc(f);
    while(c!='\0'){
        i=10*i+c-'0';
        c=fgetc(f);
    }
    i++; //The increment!
    fseek(f,pos,SEEK_SET);
    fprintf(f,"%d",i);
    fflush(f);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How were you able to post an answer?

Comment: I posted my answer just before the question was closed :)

Comment: Are you sure? I guess this is a bug with my browser then because at first I just saw the question flagged as a duplicate with 0 answers. And then after 30 min I saw the answer posted.

Comment: I don't know. As far as I know, I posted the answer while there was stilll another bash answer and while the question wasn't yet closed. Anyway.